# Which is the best way to get the data from AS400 to Excel with specific fields?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

We have a screen which has number of fields from different tables, i need to extract those fields from tables and keep the data in Excel sheet. How can i do this ?

Comment: What is your toolset? Do you have an ODBC connection from your workstation to the Db2-for-i  database?   If you make an ODBC connection (this is configuration not programming), you can use `Get External Data` in Excel , specify your SQL-query, and then get the result set on screen in Excel.  With an ODBC connection, other methods are possible.  This question is not about programming.

Comment: Another approach could be to use Java and Apache POI to update the spreadsheet.

Comment: I want to approach without using ODBC or Java. We dont have any tools to do this job so i am forced to use only IBMi

Comment: There are three methods. These are ODBC, JDBC, or Export/Import.  For some unexplained reason you want to avoid ODBC and JDBC even though they are part of IBM i access offerings. Depending on which toolset you have available, you can export the resultset of the query to a delimited file, (if necessary performing any codepage conversion that may be needed), and then import that delimited file to Excel.  You have to understand the available toolset, and mention it in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a "one-time" data-transfer, or will it be an ongoing, automated process?

IMHO, for a "one-time" data-extraction, the easiest way to accomplish that is using ODBC. Historically, I've used ODBC to  import the data into Microsoft Access. From there, it's extremely easy to export the data into Excel.

For a regularly-occurring, automated method, I think using the CpyToImpF command works the best. It takes a little trial-and-error to get the process working, but once you've got it set up, it can run in regularly scheduled job to export the data. (Google the syntax for the command, and try it yourself.)

HTH,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called iEXL which will create .Xlsx spreadsheets native on the AS400.
If you after only data from one screen we will help you and the price would we adjusted to take this into account.

WWW.iEXLSOFTWARE.COM